# Need help saving image to SQLite database in Android Studio

Tags: java, image, sqlite, android-studio, blob

I have an android studio application where the point of the app is to take pictures of the front and back of the coin, and then get information about the coin. The information and pictures are then supposed to be saved to a SQLite database.

I've already tried implementing some tips that I read on here as to how to go about this including saving the image as a bitmap then that to a byte array and then saving the byte array as a blob inside the database.

I thought that everything was right but when I run the code I get the popup basically saying that the coin pictures and info were not saved to the database; this had worked before I implemented the pictures so I know that they are somehow the problem.

Is there maybe something that I missed in the syntax? Any help with this would be appreciated.

Here's the two java classes that I'm using:

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class databaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public databaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Userdata.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB) {
        DB.execSQL(
                "create table CoinDetails (info TEXT primary key, type TEXT, quantity TEXT, heads Blob, tails Blob)"
        );


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase DB, int i, int i1) {
        DB.execSQL("drop table if exists CoinDetails");
    }

    public Boolean save_coin_data(String info, String type, String quantity, byte[] heads, byte[] tails) {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("info", info);
        contentValues.put("type", type);
        contentValues.put("quantity", quantity);
        contentValues.put("heads", heads);
        contentValues.put("tails", tails);

        long result = DB.insert("CoinDetails", null, contentValues);


        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Boolean update_coin_data(String info, String type, String quantity) {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("type", type);
        contentValues.put("quantity", quantity);

        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from CoinDetails where info = ?", new String[]{info});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            long result = DB.update("CoinDetails", contentValues, "info=?", new String[]{info});
            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean delete_coin_data(String info) {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from CoinDetails where info = ?", new String[]{info});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            long result = DB.delete("CoinDetails", "info=?", new String[]{info});
            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Cursor get_data() {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from CoinDetails", null);
        return cursor;
    }


    public byte[] bitmap_to_bytes(Bitmap bp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

insert_coin.java: (the main code that is trying to save to database)

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class insert_coin extends AppCompatActivity {

    //variables for the camera controls
    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE = 1001;

    int coinFace = 0;
    File dir;

    Button hCaptureBtn;
    ImageView himageView;

    Uri himage_uri;

    Button tCaptureBtn;
    ImageView timageView;

    Uri timage_uri;

    Bitmap h_bitmap;
    Bitmap t_bitmap;

    File h_file;
    File t_file;

    //variables for the database controls
    EditText info, type, quantity;
    Button save;
    databaseHelper DB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //initial code
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert_coin);

        //code for camera controls

        // create the path for external storage
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // create the folder for the images to be saved in

        dir = new File(path + "/COindex/");
        dir.mkdirs();

        himageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view_heads);
        hCaptureBtn = findViewById(R.id.capture_image_heads);

        hCaptureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //if system os is >= marshmallow, then get permissions
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    coinFace = 1;
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {


                        //permission not already granted, so get it
                        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                            //all permissions need to be granted
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            //pop-up for permission request
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                            //permission to write to storage and camera use is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                            //permission to read from storage and camera use is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                            //permission to read/write from/to storage is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            //only permission to read from storage is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            //only permission for camera use is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else {
                            //only permission to write to storage is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        }

                    } else {
                        //already have permission
                        openCamera();
                    }
                } else {
                    //system os < marshmallow
                    openCamera();
                }
            }

        });

        timageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view_tails);
        tCaptureBtn = findViewById(R.id.capture_image_tails);

        tCaptureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                coinFace = 2;
                //if system os is >= marshmallow, then get permissions
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                        //permission not already granted, so get it
                        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                            //all permissions need to be granted
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            //pop-up for permission request
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                            //permission to write to storage and camera use is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                            //permission to read from storage and camera use is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                            //permission to read/write from/to storage is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            //only permission to read from storage is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            //only permission for camera use is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else {
                            //only permission to write to storage is needed
                            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        //already have permission
                        openCamera();
                    }
                } else {
                    //system os < marshmallow
                    openCamera();
                }
            }

        });

        //database control code now
        info = findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        type = findViewById(R.id.type_text);
        quantity = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text);


        save = findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        DB = new databaseHelper(this);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text_info = info.getText().toString();
                String text_type = type.getText().toString();
                String text_quantity = quantity.getText().toString();

                byte[] byte_heads = DB.bitmap_to_bytes(h_bitmap);
                byte[] byte_tails = DB.bitmap_to_bytes(t_bitmap);

                Boolean check_save_data = DB.save_coin_data(text_info, text_type, text_quantity, byte_heads, byte_tails);

                if (check_save_data == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(insert_coin.this, "New Coin(s) Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(insert_coin.this, "New Coin(s) Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void gotoMain(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        //create camera intent
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE);


    }

    //handle permission from pop-up
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //permission from pop-up = granted
                openCamera();
            } else {
                //permission from pop-up = denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        //gets called when image is captured from camera

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && coinFace == 1) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            h_bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            himageView.setImageBitmap(h_bitmap);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && coinFace == 2) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            t_bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            timageView.setImageBitmap(t_bitmap);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `long result = DB.update` is even being executed?

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow()` to get a helpful exception. Guessing the database file schema is not updated after you added columns there (you can uninstall your app to recreate the database file). Also note that Android sqlite does not work well with large >= 2MB rows, such as ones with image blobs.

Comment: You might also consider saving the path to the image in the database, rather than the actual blob of the image. It will certainly decrease the size of the database.... something to think about.